# How can include case sensitive header files in MAC OS?

Tags: macos, makefile, c++14, clang++

My code is having two header files with same name but different case.(For ex:- `dataStore.h` and `DataStore.h`)
It is a maintenance project so I can not change the name of the files.
While running the make file, it is giving a warning as below:

**specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]**

And after that it fails.
Adding `-Wnonportable-include-path` in the `makefile` has no effect overall.
If anybody has used the above flag and it worked on MAC OS or any other way to solve this issue, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
.
|-- capital
|   `-- Data.h
|-- main.c
|-- main.o
`-- small
    `-- data.h
```

```
#include "data.h"

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wnonportable-include-path"
#include "Data.h"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

```
> gcc -c main.c -I./small -I./capital
```

However, note that this will not solve your issue. The problem you have is that both: `data.h` and `Data.h` point to the same file. macOS has quasi case sensitive file system.

**Walking around the issue**

I guess you might be forced to slightly change your legacy code.

```
.
|-- capital
|   `-- Data.h
|-- link
|   `-- Data.h -> ../capital/Data.h
|-- main.c
|-- main.o
`-- small
    `-- data.h
```

and inside `main.c`

```
#include "data.h"
#include "./link/Data.h"

int main() {
  smallf();
  capitalf();
  return 0;
}
```

and then

```
> gcc -c main.c -I. -I./small -I./capital
```